# Make height of DIV to be at least the screen height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The main content div `#page-content-wrapper` is shaded a light grey in color.

How can the height of this div be extended such that the bottom of this div is at the bottom of the screen? `height: 100%;` does not seem to work.

Content is growable to beyond 1 viewport height, forcing vertical scroll to be necessary.

**CSS**

```
#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #ddd;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Bootply**: http://www.bootply.com/kkrDITPGrO

[image]

Comment: if you use position:absolute, then use coordonates to size content: top:0; + bottom:0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `height: 100vh` ... or give `#wrapper` and `html, body` also `height: 100%`

For an element to respond to a height using percent, its parent need a height, and if the parent also use percent, you need to go all the way to the html/body element for it to be able to calculate its height on something other than `auto`.

[Updated bootply](http://www.bootply.com/35jRiUD6TC)

---

*Update based on comment*

For content to be able to grow, use `min-height: 100vh` ... or `min-height: 100%` using the same "percent" principle as above

```
#page-content-wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

[Updated booply](http://www.bootply.com/lwv8Y9b75K)

Comment: min-height: 100vh ?

Comment: @circusdei Question says: _...that the bottom of this div is at the bottom of the screen?_, which I interpret as not growable

Comment: overflow: scroll then? looks like the grey container could possible have lots of content

Comment: @circusdei If that question comes up, then yes, but I wait adding that since I don't know what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include that the content can grow beyond 1 viewport height

Comment: @kpie No, the viewport meta tells mobile browser how to scale etc., not whether the `vh` unit work or not

Comment: @Nyxynyx Updated my answer, is there something missing, and if so, what can I do to complete it?